# how to get sender id from fb page api

Tags: api, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph, facebook-marketing-api

hi guys im doing fb chatbot and how to get client's profile id by fb api,
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id= { 100001533612613 }

its events from request but sender id is not actually user profile id
`

```
EVENT:  {
  sender: { id: '6298043600210280' },
  recipient: { id: '111024461575357' },
  timestamp: 1667695330939,
  message: {
    mid: 'm_PAE6AYsLvGF8GTQ9_vbvrVh-86tQzbwIEgWdvzHpqG_FErNdi8E1Ji48LyQH2hRl1NGxyTMBcS6uxgE_mS9KLA',
    text: '1234'
  }
}
```

`

```
    const url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/v15.0/me/messages?access_token=' + process.env.PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN
    // console.log(url)
    if (!event.message.is_echo) {

        console.log('EVENT: ', event);
        const message = event.message.text
        const senderID = event.sender.id
        const number = event.message.text
```

Comment: Correct it is a page scoped user ID and that is by design.

Comment: is it possible to get sender profile url

Comment: Matching between page-scoped user id, and an app-scoped user id, is only available for businesses. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/identity/id-matching